# Display first image's caption

Tags: images

I'd like to display the first image uploaded to a post plus its caption.
The code below (functions.php + single.php) displays the image, but I have been able to figure out how to display the caption.
Maybe there are simpler ways of doing this than my code.
NOTE! Image and caption are displayed only if there is an image and if there is a caption.

Code in functions.php

```
function main_image() {
$files = get_children('post_parent='.get_the_ID().'&post_type=attachment
&post_mime_type=image&order=desc');
  if($files) :
    $keys = array_reverse(array_keys($files));
    $j=0;
    $num = $keys[$j];
    $image=wp_get_attachment_image($num, 'large', true);
    $imagepieces = explode('"', $image);
    $imagepath = $imagepieces[1];
    $main=wp_get_attachment_url($num);
        $template=get_template_directory();
        $the_title=get_the_title();
    print "<img src='$main' alt='$the_title' class='frame' /><br><br>";
  endif;
}

- - - - - - - - - - - - 

Code in single.php
<!-- Image 1 -->
<?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) {
   echo main_image();
} ?>
```

Comment: You check for a featured image (`has_post_thumbnail()`) but then you don't use the featured image. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Every post with one or more images has a featured image, and I use it for checking if a post has image/s. The code I have I'll use for displaying image no 2, 3 and so on, and therefore I need to be able to display each images caption.